# calculate 2 days prior and 2 days after sales

Tags: mysql, sql

wants to calculate 2 days prior and 2 days after sales

total_2_days_prior_sales = before 2 days to current date sales sum
total_2_days_prior_sales = from current date to next 2 days sales sum

**Requirement:**

[image]

**Live Code:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d88bee/15

**My Try:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    end_date date,
    sales int
);

INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-01',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-01',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-02',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-02',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-03',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-04',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-05',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-06',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-07',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-08',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-08',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-09',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-10',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-11',10);
INSERT INTO test (end_Date, sales)
VALUES ('2022-01-12',10);
```

**Code:**

```
select 
end_Date,
-- DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL 2 day),
-- DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL -2 day),
-- DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL 0 day),
SUM(sales) as CurrentSales,
SUM(case when end_Date between DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL 2 day) and DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL 0 day) then sales else 0 end) total_2_days_prior_sales,
SUM(case when end_Date between DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL 0 day) and DATE_SUB(date(end_Date), INTERVAL -2 day) then sales else 0 end) total_2_days_after_sales
from test
group by end_Date
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.6 does not support window functions and CTE, you can use subqueries to get the totals for prior sales and after sales, like this

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT SUM(t.sales) 
                 FROM test t 
                 WHERE t.end_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(s.end_Date, INTERVAL 1 day) AND s.end_date
                 GROUP BY s.end_date) total_2_days_prior_sales,
    (SELECT SUM(t.sales) 
                 FROM test t 
                 WHERE t.end_date BETWEEN s.end_date AND DATE_ADD(s.end_Date, INTERVAL 1 day)
                 GROUP BY s.end_date) total_2_days_after_sales                 
FROM (
    SELECT
        end_Date,
        SUM(sales) CurrentSales
    FROM test
    GROUP BY end_Date
) s
```

Output

| end_Date | CurrentSales | total_2_days_prior_sales | total_2_days_after_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 20 | 20 | 40 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 40 | 30 |
| 2022-01-03 | 10 | 30 | 20 |
| 2022-01-04 | 10 | 20 | 20 |
| 2022-01-05 | 10 | 20 | 20 |
| 2022-01-06 | 10 | 20 | 20 |
| 2022-01-07 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2022-01-08 | 20 | 30 | 30 |
| 2022-01-09 | 10 | 30 | 20 |
| 2022-01-10 | 10 | 20 | 20 |
| 2022-01-11 | 10 | 20 | 20 |
| 2022-01-12 | 10 | 20 | 10 |

---

If to change the interval from 2 days to 3 days, output is like this

| end_Date | CurrentSales | total_3_days_prior_sales | total_3_days_after_sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 20 | 20 | 50 |
| 2022-01-02 | 20 | 40 | 40 |
| 2022-01-03 | 10 | 50 | 30 |
| 2022-01-04 | 10 | 40 | 30 |
| 2022-01-05 | 10 | 30 | 30 |
| 2022-01-06 | 10 | 30 | 40 |
| 2022-01-07 | 10 | 30 | 40 |
| 2022-01-08 | 20 | 40 | 40 |
| 2022-01-09 | 10 | 40 | 30 |
| 2022-01-10 | 10 | 40 | 30 |
| 2022-01-11 | 10 | 30 | 20 |
| 2022-01-12 | 10 | 30 | 10 |

You can check a sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d88bee/71)

---

Also you can use a self JOIN with your table and calculate sub totals conditionally like this

```
SELECT
    s.end_date,
    s.sales,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.end_date <= s.end_date
             THEN t.sales
        END) prev_sales,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.end_date >= s.end_date 
             THEN t.sales
        END) after_sales
FROM (
    SELECT
        end_date,
        SUM(sales) sales
    FROM test
    GROUP BY end_date
) s
JOIN test t ON t.end_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(s.end_Date, INTERVAL 1 day) AND DATE_ADD(s.end_Date, INTERVAL 1 day)
GROUP BY end_date
```

This query produces the same output.

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/nCSPT1wq)

In general, a join should perform better.

Also you need a composite index on the end_date and sales columns in your table.

Comment: You need a composite index on the `end_date` and `sales` columns in your table

Comment: it is not working, if I change the duration from 2 days to 3 days

Comment: @JunedAnsari, then you need to use a different query. I updated the answer with the new query, the sqlfiddle link and added the output.

Comment: Hi @Alexy, you have used subquery, it will be executed for each row. i wonder how much it will take time if I have 10M rows.

Comment: the same calculation I need to do on the other 2 fields also so it is taking too much time can you suggest to me how to optimize it?

Comment: @JunedAnsari, you can try a self join, take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Suggest composite index (or possibly `PRIMARY KEY` of `(end_date, sales)`